# sublimetext3: поломался плагин minifier для CSS

Tags: css, sublime-text, плагин

перестал минифицировать CSS файлы. Вместо этого выдает код страницы https://cssminifier.com/
для JS нормально работает.

Кто-нибудь побеждал этот баг? 
Или может подскажете какой-нибудь другой хороший плагин/редактор?

Работаю на win7 бесправной, может важно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

победил. Оказывается для класса, что CSS обрабатывает, поменялся протокол сервиса(на http**s**).
В общем поставил плагин вручную, в файле cssminifiercall.py, что в папке compillers поменял этот протокол:

```
class CssminifierCall(BaseCall):

def exec_request(self):
    ua = 'Sublime Text - cssminifier'
    query = {
        'input': self.original }
    url = "https://cssminifier.com/raw"
```

вот так этот кусок должен вывглядеть